# Proofs in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

I've recently understood that proofs are a very essential part in real analysis, and I seem to struggle at doing rigorous proofs of certain statements.

What I'm looking for is basically topics that have to do with limits, so using the epsilon delta definition so say, as well as proofs including the topics regarding injectivity, surjectivity, monotonicity, and so forth.

I'm asking you guys if you know any good books / pdfs with a collection of a bunch of proofs, maybe with some excercises included, in real analysis?

Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend Dr. Peyam's youtube channel. He works through all sorts of problems of varying difficulty and is super thorough. You can always see the problem, try it out yourself, and then watch the rest of the video for a worked out solution. Also, it might not be the case for you, but lots of the time, difficulty proving something comes from a lack of conceptual understanding about WHAT it is you are working with, so bolstering that can definitely help too (again, Peyam is a great resource for understanding the intuiton, meaning, definitions of concepts in real analysis).

Comment: I really like "Understanding Analysis" by Stephen Abbott for real analysis. But it is more of a textbook and can be pretty dense without an instructor or course helping you through it. However it does give some really nice conceptual ideas about analysis, more than just problem solving

Comment: I recommend the youtube video lectures by Francis Su   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqEyWLGvvdw&list=PL0E754696F72137EC  It is a good start. One of the best books that explain delta-epsilon proofs is Spivak's calculus and Inroduction real analysis, by Sherbert & Bartle.

Comment: When you say you struggle with writing rigorous proofs, what in particular do you struggle with?  Sometimes as a student it can be hard to distinguish between crucial-yet-subtle distinctions and pedantry; there's plenty of both at the university level.

Comment: Thank you all above for your tips! I appreciate it. @user3716267 it's more about that I don't really know where to start when doing a proof. I know that's essential to learn all definitions and such, but I realize that I do make my proofs too complicated. Still, I think the hardest part for me is knowing when a proof is valid or not, if you understand, and this is probably what keeps me making my proofs to complicated. In the end, it looks like a complete mess haha. No but seriously, I'm "scared" that the proof won't be enough, so I continue to provide too much "information" :/

Comment: Even within the realm of "rigorous proof-writing," there's no real universal standard on what makes a proof convincing or valid.  It always depends on context.  Don't worry too much about meeting some arbitrary standard of "validity" - worry instead about whether or not your reasoning makes sense.

Comment: Here's [a nice bit from Terry Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/theres-more-to-mathematics-than-rigour-and-proofs/) about the purpose of rigorous proof in the grander scheme of mathematics, which might help you determine where to direct your efforts.

Comment: @user3716267 Thank you, I'll check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of comments have provided a few answers already, but to give a more "academic" solution:

1. A number of courses will use a book titled "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" by Rudin, with the book often being dubbed "Baby Rudin". This would be your most formal, basic introduction to the topic.
2. For an open-source (free) solution, the two part series of "Basic Analysis" by Jirí Lebl does effectively what Baby Rudin does without the price tag. You can find it [here](https://www.jirka.org/ra/).
3. For a solution based in proving all of first-year/high-school calculus rigorously, I strongly recommend "Calculus with Applications" by Peter Lax and Maria Terrell. They go through everything in early calculus step-by-step and prove it, and they have a second book for multivariable calculus.
4. For a very early introduction to proofs, I would recommend picking up a discrete math book (or open-source PDF). I have used "Discrete Mathematics - An Open Introduction" found [here](http://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi3.html), so I recommend that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll be checking the links soon. Greatly appreciated :)